# How do i make next button go to next Frame? GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

How do I make the next button go to the next Frame in this GUI? I need to have it where I can click next to display 20 more details:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FilledFrameViewer
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();

      /*JButton button = new JButton*/
      JButton nextButton = new JButton("NEXT");
      JLabel label = new JLabel("Frame 1.");

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(nextButton);
      panel.add(label);
      frame.add(panel);

      final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
      final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 100;
      frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
      frame.setTitle("A frame with two components");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could insert some code in your question to see what is the problem.

Comment: I havnt much thats why im stuck

Comment: , import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FilledFrameViewer
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();

      /*JButton button = new JButton*/
      JButton nextButton = new JButton("NEXT");
      JLabel label = new JLabel("Frame 1.");

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(nextButton);
      panel.add(label);
      frame.add(panel);

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
      final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 100;
      frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
      frame.setTitle("A frame with two components");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

Comment: Wait, insert this in a question. Not in a comment. You have edit button below a question

Comment: The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/300257

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide or show the frame, you can use like this

JFrame f1 = new JFrame("Frame 1");
JFrame f2 = new JFrame("Frame 2");

to hide f1, call f1.setVisible(false);
to show f2, call f2.setVisible(true);

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear. Do you want to move a *JButton* to another *JFrame*? I don't think you can manage that without dynamic programming or such (I guess?).

You should look through a tutorial of the Swing components from Oracle http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

And see your comments. I agree having multiple *JFrame* is a bad habit.

**Edit**

Use the eventlistner (see other answer) and make it follow a switch case? Then there you can make it display like a dialog or change a *JLable* inside your *JFrame*?

Dialog tutorial here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html.
I think you should go with a lable and change it's text.

```
JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListner(

private int counter = 0;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

    counter++;

    switch(counter){

        case 1: somelable.setText("Your text here");

    };

}));
```

I wrote this on free hand but I guess something like this would work?

Comment: No what I want is when I click next it will go to the next jframe and display info on a different person

Comment: you should not have many jframes! Gilbert Le Blanc already pointet out that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/300257)!

Comment: Yes but it's the question I have is to use a next frame.

Comment: Then I guess you have to custom make 20 JFrames each with a next button added a actionlistener which creates a new JFrame (the next one in line) and hides the current one showing

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit the codes in your next frame...
Example for your NextFrame,

```
public class NextFrame
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      private static FilledFrameViewer parentFrame; //ADD THIS FOR CONNECTION TO FIRST FRAME

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    NextFrame frame = new NextFrame(null); //CHANGES MADE HERE
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

      public NextFrame(FilledFrameViewer f) { //CHANGES MADE HERE
      this.parentFrame = f; //CHANGES MADE HERE
        setTitle("Personal Assistant");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Yes...and also you'll have to add some things in the Next button...

Example:

```
 btnNext = new JButton();
    btnNext.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            goNext();
            {
                private void goNext(){
                                    NextFrame nextframe= new NextFrame(null);
                                    nextframe.setVisible(true);
            }
            }

    });
```